Version incompatible for ASR Mobility Installation
For Ubuntu 22.04 of the kernel version 6.5.0-1022-aws, @AzureSupport recommending to use the generic kernels
So, May I know for which AWS EC2 Ubuntu Machines, contains the generic kernels versions exits to migrate the VM from AWS to Azure
